# Error in Example from prisma about how to implement a graphql API

Tags: graphql, prisma

I am trying to follow this example:

[Prisma graphql example](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/typescript/graphql#using-the-graphql-api.)

At the following step (section 2.1) the code breaks.

```
Update the User object type to include the `profile field:

// ./src/schema/user.ts

builder.prismaObject('User', {
  fields: (t) => ({
    id: t.exposeInt('id'),
    name: t.exposeString('name', { nullable: true }),
    email: t.exposeString('email'),
    posts: t.relation('posts'),
    profile: t.relation('profile'),
  }),
})
```

Also, I did complete the next step: "2.2. Add a createProfile GraphQL mutation".  If I remove the line for the profile from the user, then everything works.

The error is:

PothosSchemaError: Ref ObjectRef has not been implemented
at new PothosError (C:\prisma_postgresql_api\typescript_graphql\node_modules@pothos\core\src\errors.ts:7:5)
at new PothosSchemaError (C:\prisma_postgresql_api\typescript_graphql\node_modules@pothos\core\src\errors.ts:14:5)
at ConfigStore.getTypeConfig (C:\prisma_postgresql_api\typescript_graphql\node_modules@pothos\core\src\config-store.ts:289:13)
at BuildCache.getType (C:\prisma_postgresql_api\typescript_graphql\node_modules@pothos\core\src\build-cache.ts:444:41)
at BuildCache.getOutputType (C:\prisma_postgresql_api\typescript_graphql\node_modules@pothos\core\src\build-cache.ts:458:23)
at BuildCache.buildOutputTypeParam (C:\prisma_postgresql_api\typescript_graphql\node_modules@pothos\core\src\build-cache.ts:283:36)
at BuildCache.buildFields (C:\prisma_postgresql_api\typescript_graphql\node_modules@pothos\core\src\build-cache.ts:345:20)
at BuildCache.getObjectFields (C:\prisma_postgresql_api\typescript_graphql\node_modules@pothos\core\src\build-cache.ts:410:31)
at BuildCache.getFields (C:\prisma_postgresql_api\typescript_graphql\node_modules@pothos\core\src\build-cache.ts:425:19)
at fields (C:\prisma_postgresql_api\typescript_graphql\node_modules@pothos\core\src\build-cache.ts:558:26)
[ERROR] 13:55:21 PothosSchemaError: Ref ObjectRef has not been implemented

Here is what I have for the profile.ts

```
import { builder } from "../builder";
import { prisma } from '../db'
import { UserUniqueInput } from './user';

builder.prismaObject('Profile', {
  fields: (t) => ({
    id: t.exposeInt('id'),
    bio: t.exposeString('bio', { nullable: true }),
    user: t.relation('user'),
  }),
})

builder.mutationField('createProfile', (t) =>
  t.prismaField({
    type: 'Profile',
    args: {
      bio: t.arg.string({ required: true }),
      data: t.arg({ type: UserUniqueInput })
    },
    resolve: async (query, _parent, args, _context) =>
      prisma.profile.create({
        ...query,
        data: {
          bio: args.bio,
          user: {
            connect: {
              id: args.data?.id || undefined,
              email: args.data?.email || undefined
            }
          }
        }
      })
  })
)
```

Here is what I have for the user.ts

```
import { builder } from '../builder'
import { prisma } from '../db'
import { PostCreateInput } from './post'

builder.prismaObject('User', {
  fields: (t) => ({
    id: t.exposeInt('id'),
    name: t.exposeString('name', { nullable: true }),
    email: t.exposeString('email'),
    posts: t.relation('posts'),
    profile: t.relation('profile'),
  }),
})

export const UserUniqueInput = builder.inputType('UserUniqueInput', {
  fields: (t) => ({
    id: t.int(),
    email: t.string(),
  }),
})

const UserCreateInput = builder.inputType('UserCreateInput', {
  fields: (t) => ({
    email: t.string({ required: true }),
    name: t.string(),
    posts: t.field({ type: [PostCreateInput] }),
  }),
})

builder.queryFields((t) => ({
  allUsers: t.prismaField({
    type: ['User'],
    resolve: (query) => prisma.user.findMany({ ...query }),
  }),
}))

builder.mutationFields((t) => ({
  signupUser: t.prismaField({
    type: 'User',
    args: {
      data: t.arg({
        type: UserCreateInput,
        required: true,
      }),
    },
    resolve: (query, parent, args) => {
      return prisma.user.create({
        ...query,
        data: {
          email: args.data.email,
          name: args.data.name,
          posts: {
            create: (args.data.posts ?? []).map((post) => ({
              title: post.title,
              content: post.content ?? undefined,
            })),
          },
        },
      })
    },
  }),
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instructions need to add the line "import './profile'" to the ./src/schema/index.ts